# AIR and sqLite : if table exists conditional

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

How do I get a Boolean value in AS3 whether a table or an entry exists in the database?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As opposed to finding it manually with SQL you should use the built in Schema information classes/functions. Here is an example of how it would work.

```
public function doesTableExist(connection:SQLConnection, tableName:String):Boolean
{
    connection.loadSchema();
    var schema:SQLSchemaResult = connection.getSchemaResult();

    for each (var table:SQLTableSchema in schema.tables)
    {
        if (table.name.toLowerCase() == tableName.toLowerCase())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is the best way. AS3 SQLite does not support PRAGMA. [Official Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd47bd22bdd97276f1365b8c112629d7c47c-8000.html#WSd47bd22bdd97276f-5ebd067e1262b61342b-8000)

Comment: This does indeed work best. A few heeds of warning: 1.) I would suggest wrapping this whole function in a try-catch statement, because if you have NO tables at all in your database, an error will get thrown stating there is no schema to load, and of course cause issues during runtime. 2.) If you are using an async database connection you *MUST* make sure it has fully loaded before you start checking the schema, or else you will get an error complaining about the connection being bad.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple statement to achieve boolean value, but you can:

1. use `PRAGMA table_info(tbl_status)` and analize list.
2. try to execute `SELECT col FROM table_name` in try...catch block, in case of error simply set variable to bool.

BTW, maybe you need to use `IF NOT EXISTS` in create statement for table, index creation...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I do already have `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, but was wondering how to get this in as3

Comment: didn't get around to test it yet as I switched to a DataObject, but will give it a try when I get a chance, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

can be useful for someone - for async connection:

```
connection.loadSchema();
connection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.SCHEMA, check_result);

private function check_result(event:SQLEvent):void{
var schema:SQLSchemaResult = connection.getSchemaResult();
//as above
}
```