# Android Java, database insert, not working

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("database.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                 db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
                 db.setLockingEnabled(true);
                 db.setVersion(1); 

                 String dropTableA = "DROP TABLE if exists databaseA";
                 String createTableA = "CREATE TABLE databaseA(" +
                 "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                 "Nome TEXT, Telefone INTEGER)";

                 String dropTableB = "DROP TABLE if exists databaseB";
                 String createTableB = "CREATE TABLE databaseB(" +
                 "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                 "Localidade TEXT, " +
                 "fk_dbA_id INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT dbA_id REFERENCES databaseA(_id) ON " +
                 "DELETE CASCADE)";

                 String nomeValue = nome.getText().toString();
                 String telValue = tel.getText().toString();
                 String localValue = local.getText().toString();
                 //PROBLEM MAY LIE HERE
                 String insertA = "insert into databaseA(_id, Nome, Telefone) values(1, "+nomeValue+", "+telValue+")"; 
                 //PROBLEM MAY LIE HERE
                 String insertB = "insert into databaseB(_id, Localidade, fk_dbA_id) values(1, "+localValue+", 1)"; 

                 db.execSQL(dropTableA);
                 db.execSQL(createTableA);
                 db.execSQL(dropTableB);
                 db.execSQL(createTableB);
                 db.execSQL(insertA);
                 db.execSQL(insertB);
```

Comment: Did u try db = openOrCreateDatabase("database.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)

Comment: if you run in the emulator, you can `cd` to your database folder, and can use sql sentence to check the database and table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String insertA = "insert into databaseA(_id, Nome, Telefone) values(1, "+nomeValue+", "+telValue+")"; 
             //PROBLEM MAY LIE HERE
             String insertB = "insert into databaseB(_id, Localidade, fk_dbA_id) values(1, "+localValue+", 1)";
```

I Think you can write it like this:

```
 String insertA = "insert into databaseA(_id, Nome, Telefone) values(1, \""+nomeValue+"\", "+telValue+")"; 
             //PROBLEM MAY LIE HERE
             String insertB = "insert into databaseB(_id, Localidade, fk_dbA_id) values(1, \""+localValue+"\", 1)";
```

Comment: if you want to check the table exist or not then you can check by query  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists

Comment: i think it worked, how can i see my database, the easiest way please

Comment: oh if you want to see your database you need to get its .sqlite file from file-Explorer/data/data/your_Package_name/database/your_file_name.db      pull the file from their to desktop,Then change its extension with .sqlite and open it with sqliteManager in firefox it shows you all data.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two lines:

```
String insertA = "insert into databaseA(_id, Nome, Telefone) values(1, '"+nomeValue+"', '"+telValue+"')"; 

         String insertB = "insert into databaseB(_id, Localidade, fk_dbA_id) values(1, '"+localValue+"', 1)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding semicolons to your sql statements?

Instead of:

```
String createTableA = "CREATE TABLE databaseA(" +
             "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
             "Nome TEXT, Telefone INTEGER)";
```

Try:

```
String createTableA = "CREATE TABLE databaseA(" +
             "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
             "Nome TEXT, Telefone INTEGER);";
```

I know in Oracle it's important. I know in my SQLite I always include them and mine works. I think the ";" in Oracle/SQLite kind of works like the "go" in Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

db.execSQL("INSERT INTO playlist (name) Values('" + name + "')");

Answer (score 0):

//change your String telValue to int.

```
int telValue = Integer.parseInt(tel.getText().toString());
```