# sqlite - how to check if table exists before completing inserts?

Tags: sqlite

What is the best SQL for a SQLite database to effectively do:

```
If Database Table Exists then
  - create table
  - insert row
  - insert row (i.e. for startup data)
end
```

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To check that your table exists or not, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='myTable' and type='table';
```

Comment: ok - so you think it best to keep the inserts as separate sql statements I assume? thanks

Comment: For TEMP tables, you must look at sqlite_temp_master.

Answer (score 9):

You can let Sqlite itself check this out for you:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <table_name> ...;
```

Follow link for documentation:
https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: This is the way!

Comment: Well for the database itself yes but what if I have lot of things to do in the app before even calling this? I can save compute time and resources if I am  able to check before.

Comment: This is the right answer!

Answer (score 5):

Use this code

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='yourTableName';
```

if returning array count is equal to 1 its means table exist else not exist.