# sqlite3 error: no such table: when checking if table exists

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have read several posts but still cannot figure out what is wrong here. 
I have a c++ wrapper to call the sqlite. I want to test if the table exists before it is created, by reading [check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists), I use the following sql statement to check a table exists

> "SELECT name FROM test.db WHERE type='table' AND name='table1';"

The main code is the following:

```
static int callback(void *db, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
  for(int i=0; i<argc; ++i){
    printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
  }
  return 0;
}

class SqliteAccessor {
public:
open(){ sqlite3_open("test.db", &m_db); }
createTable1(){
  string sql = "CREATE TABLE table1(one TEXT);";
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    printf("SQL error: %s", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  }
}     
hasTable1(){
  string sql = "SELECT name FROM test.db WHERE type='table' AND name='table1'";
  char *zErrMsg = 0;
  int rc = sqlite3_exec(m_db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
  if( rc != SQLITE_OK ){
    printf("SQL error: %s", zErrMsg); // Error: no such table: test.db 
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
  } 
}
private:
sqlite3* m_db;
}

main(){
  SqliteAccessor sql;
  sql.open(); // success;
  sql.createTable1(); // success;
  sql.hasTable1(); // fail
}
```

I also tried with cli api:

```
sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> create table table1(one varchar(10));
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test.db;
Error: no such table: test.db
sqlite> SELECT name FROM test.db WHERE type='table' AND name='table1';
Error: no such table: test.db
// however, if I run .tables, then it is there.
sqlite> .tables
table1
```

it is the same error, but why such error? it is the lastest sqlite amalgamation version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into sqlite_master instead.

`SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name LIKE '%your_table_name%'`

Comment: aha, It seems I have to select from "test.db.sqlite_master", is this "sqlite_master" a built-in table that lists all the tables?

Comment: If i use "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table1';" it will be OK. but how can I specify which database then?

Comment: Do you have more than one database? I'm not sure if it's possible yo hace several "databases"

Comment: yes. One is working, the other one is the saved backup

Comment: So you'd hace yo open two different connections.