# username already exists using sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to show in Signup Part of My app.In signup if user enter duplicate name then "username already exists " error msg should be shown.anyone help me.....??

Comment: Help : You should create a web service & write business logic for webservice integration in Android Application.

Comment: Tell us what have you tried so far and what error do you get ...

Comment: I did't try anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check in SQLite whether a table exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists)

Comment: Means you want to set Error Message in editText?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//If username Already Exists
            if (userName.equals(storedUsername)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Username Already Exists!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return;
            }
```