# How to check table exist in sqlite using java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

How to check if table exist in sqlite using java.

I have used the code

```
 String sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'COMPANY'";
 System.out.println("Sql Sqlite" + sql);
 int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Dont Know its correct or not, I'm new to sqlite please help.

Comment: You're not updating anything, so why are you using `executeUpdate()`?

Comment: @augustoccesar This question is actually about how to run a query.

Comment: @CL. it makes sense... The question is not very clear, but I see your point. Removed the flag.

Comment: @augustoccesar. I just want to check, if the given table exist or not.

Comment: @VikasSingh I see... I believe there is an answer for you question already on SO. The post that I marked as duplicated, there is some examples of how to do this. I believe the answer bellow is a link to the same post that I flagged, check it out :)

Answer (score -1):

I did not find any native methods in Sqlite to check if a table exists, but from the question below a way to do that is doing a select in the table.

[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists1)

Another way to do it in java I found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-tables.htm), but not sure if will work .

```
 String sql = "CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE " +
               "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
               " first VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
               " age INTEGER, " + 
               " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
try{
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
}catch(Exception se){
  //the table already exists
  se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That answer is for Android, not JDBC.

Comment: @CL. Yes, you're right, I already edited my answer, hope this help.

Comment: This question is not about creating a table.

Comment: @CL. The question is about check if an table exists, and a way to check that is trying to create the table again, you will get an exception if it exists, may it is not the best solution or is not the best practice but is a way to check if a table exists.