# I tried using sqlite on ionic but it keeps giving me 5 errors

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS developer (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT, skill TEXT, yearsOfExperience INTEGER );
INSERT INTO developer(name, skill, yearsOfExperience) VALUES ('Simon', 'Ionic', '4');
INSERT INTO developer(name, skill, yearsOfExperience) VALUES ('Jorge', 'Firebase', '2');
INSERT INTO developer(name, skill, yearsOfExperience) VALUES ('Max', 'Startup', '5');
```

error:

Incorrect syntax near 'IF', Expecting'.', ID, or QOUTED_ID.

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected.

Incorrect syntax near 'developer'.

Incorrect syntax near 'developer'. Expecting '('.

Incorrect syntax near 'id'. Expecting '(' or SELECT.

Comment: You forgot to include your errors... (And should probably put all those statements into a code block so it's easier to read).

Comment: okay done errors are now added

Comment: Hello Aeron. I see you've posted an error. What are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear what you're asking, and as this is a Q & A site that's important.

Comment: well i just want to simply create a table but it keeps getting me these errors. sorry im new to this community

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new information or updated descriptions about the question.

Comment: Which version of SQLite are you using exactly? If it's older 3.3 this answer seems to imply it might not have a support for the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists/5205530#5205530