# How to call a function only once on window is loaded in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm building a cordova project in which I have created a database 
The database includes a table for which I want to insert ID column for table when window is loaded...
**The problem I'm facing is every time I load the page same ID's are getting inserted**......
*And I want to insert only once after that whenever I load the page ID's must not get inserted*
....
Code is given below

```
window.onload = function(){
db = openDatabase('Timetable', '1.0', 'Time Table', 10 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,monday TEXT,tuesday TEXT,wednesday TEXT,thursday TEXT,friday TEXT,saturday TEXT,sunday TEXT)');
for (var i=1;i<=24;i++){
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO schedule(ID) VALUES(?)',[i]);  
}
```

}

Output : 
[Output of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Aze.png)
[Output of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAcxp.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could add a `where` clause to your SQL to prevent insertion of duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a problem about cordova or javascript, but rather a pure logic problem.

What you need to do is check if the `schedule` table exists (or if the IDs are already in the table), and if it does not add your 24 IDs.
See [How do I check in SQLite whether a table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists) for reference.

Something like this

```
window.onload = function() {
  db = openDatabase('Timetable', '1.0', 'Time Table', 10 * 1024 * 1024);

  // Check for schedule table presence with something like this
  // SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';
  // NOTE : I have not tested this code syntax. This is just to give you the idea, I don't know how to write correctly sqlite commands.
  var isScheduleCreated = false;
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    var result = tx.executeSql("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='schedule'");
    if (result) isScheduleCreated = true;
  });

  if (isScheduleCreated === false) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,monday TEXT,tuesday TEXT,wednesday TEXT,thursday TEXT,friday TEXT,saturday TEXT,sunday TEXT)');
      for (var i=1;i<=24;i++) {
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO schedule(ID) VALUES(?)',[i]);  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Remarks

```
db.transaction((tx) => {
  // ...
}
```

uses [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to define the function, but it is exactly the same as writing it like this. It's just easier and a habit of mine.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
  // ...
}
```