# How to check if TABLE exists before ALTER query?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, alter-table, react-native-sqlite-storage

Before adding (ALTER) new column to table I want to check if that table exists. Because app is crashing since table is not present and we tried to add column to it.

I tried "Alter table if exist table_name add column abc" but no luck.

I want to do this in 1 query.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604121/5841306) (or the one just below this, in vote descendingly ordered) answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. That will give  if table is exist but how to combine it with ALTER query is my main concern.