# How to query table only when it exists in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

In a desktop app, I'm trying to allow users to import data from another computer via SQLite .DB file.  There are two completely different database versions that should be importable (current and legacy).  Basically, I just need to figure out which database type the user has selected before I proceed.  I'm expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN
        (SELECT count(*) 
        FROM sqlite_schema 
        WHERE type = 'table' 
        AND name = 'current_only_table') = 1
    THEN 
        (SELECT col FROM current_only_table)
    ELSE 
        (SELECT '')
END
```

But when `current_only_table`
does not exist, I get a `no such table` error.  I'm expecting it to just run the `ELSE` portion.

It's worth noting that I know the `WHEN` portion is working properly, because replacing `SELECT col FROM current_only_table` with `SELECT 'col FROM current_only_table'` I get `col FROM current_only_table` when the table exists and   when it does not (as expected).

I've found a ton of somewhat similar questions (most notably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists)), but I'm not seeing any that answer my question.

As a workaround, I intend to simply run the query to get the table count.  Then, I'll use some logic in the app to determine whether it's necessary to run another query to get the `col` value.  However, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.